# java undefined reference to `main' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: java, linux

I have a problem compiling a `java` file. 
My command for compile: javac -g HelloWorld.java

I wrote a simple hello world program:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

I'm using `putty`, and I'm connecting with `ssh`. I am getting this error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.14.1/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:109: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You've shown us the code, but no indication of what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: Right now I just want to compile it.

Comment: Do you have Java setup correctly?

Comment: Can you show the command you use to compile ?

Comment: I am connectinglinux computer somewhere else, actually from my school. and they are correct @KeerthiRamanathan

Comment: javac -g HelloWorld.java @CristianMeneses

Comment: Try my solution below

Comment: And what version of `javac` are you using? Fundamentally we shouldn't have to ask all of these questions one at a time - please take care to provide all the relevant information in the question to start with in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, you are using the gcc javac compiler, which doesn't work as the SUN/Oracle implementation.

I guess you need to add `--main=HelloWorld` to the command. Since several classes may have a 'main' method, the linker needs to be told which one to use.

Also, you might want to add -o , otherwise, you'll get a 'a.out' file, which is the default executable name for the GNU compilers (and any C compiler actually).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would just uninstall the useless GNU 'Java compiler'. It isn't really any such thing, just an uncertified approximation to a small and shrinking subset.